# not getting magento image url from bestseller

Tags: magento

I wrote some code for best-seller product in magento but

I m not getting product image url ....

I need small image for the gallery..

I m developing bestseller slider .....the whole thing is good

but only i m not getting image url...

my code

```
$current_category = Mage::registry('current_category');
        $is_category_filter = Mage::getStoreConfig('productslider/product_setting/category_filter');
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
                            ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
                            ->addOrderedQty()
                            ->addMinimalPrice()
                            ->addTaxPercents()
                            ->addStoreFilter(); 
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInSearchFilterToCollection($collection);
        if($current_category && $is_category_filter == '1'){
            $current_category_id = Mage::registry('current_category')->getId();
            $currentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($current_category_id);
            $collection->addCategoryFilter($currentCategory);
        }
        $collection->setPageSize(30);

        $this->setProductCollection($collection);








return $collection;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(160, 225) ?>" width="160" height="225" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" /></a>
```